# Appending data to User Model in Django

Tags: django-models

Here is how my model looks like:

```
    class Maintab(models.Model):
        email = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        username = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        password = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        lab_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        type = models.CharField(max_length=255)
        def __str__(self):
             return self.username
```

I want to append the User table that looks after the login, with the username and password of my Maintab model. If only the username and password of the user table could get updated. 
Or if I could use Maintab as my Custom UserModel (but it would not have attributes like is_active, is_staff, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like creating your own user models by subclassing the existing user model is the right solution as it enables you to use the existing django code while also adding your own user attributes.

Here is a link to the Django documentation where they describe how to do this:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#using-a-custom-user-model-when-starting-a-project